# What NoSQL solution to choose for domain names database?

Tags: nosql, key-value

I have a project that stores several millions of domain names in database and perform search requests to find if domain is present in DB. The only operation I need - check if given value exists. No range queries, no additional information, nothing.

The number of queries that I make to database is rather big, for example 100'000 per one user session.

I have new database once a day and even it's possible to check what records were deleted and what added - I don't think that it's worth it. So, I am importing database to a new table and point script to a new name.

Looking for solution that can make the whole things faster, as I don't use any SQL features. Name search and import time are important for me.

My server can't store this database in memory, even half of it, so I think some NoSQL solution working from hard drive can help me.

Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much smaller and faster solution would be to use [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/eKvOPB) with the [key-value pair API](http://bit.ly/hgblLz). Berkeley DB is a database library that links into your application, so there is no client/server overhead nor separate server to install and manage. Berkeley DB is very straightforward and provides, among several APIs, a simple key-value (NoSQL) API that provides all of the basic data management routines that you would expect to find in a much larger, more complex RDBMS (indexing, secondary indexes, foreign keys), but without the overhead of a SQL engine.

Disclaimer: I am the Product Manager for Berkeley DB, so I am a little biased. That said, it was designed to do exactly what you're asking for -- straightforward, fast, scalable key-value data management without unnecessary overhead.

In fact, there are **many** "database domain" type application services that use Berkeley DB as their primary data store. Most of the open source and/or commercial LDAP implementations use Berkeley DB (including OpenLDAP, Redhat's LDAP, Sun Directory Server, etc.). Cisco, Juniper, AT&T, Alcatel, Mitel, Motorola and many others use Berkeley DB to manage their They use Berkeley DB for their gateway, authentication, and configuration management systems, They use BDB because it does exactly what they need, it's very fast, scalable and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You could get by quite nicely with just a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) if you can accept a very small false positive rate (assuming you use a large enough filter).

On the other hand, you could certainly use [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).  It makes heavy use of bloom filters, so asking for something that doesn't exist is quick, and you don't have to worry about false positives.  It's designed to handle data sets that do not fit into memory, so performance degredation there is quite smooth.

Importing any amount of data should be quick -- on a normal machine, Cassandra can handle about 15k writes per second.

Answer (score 0):

Many options here. Berkeley DB certainly does the job and is probably one of the simplest solutions. Just as simple: store everything in memcached, then you have the option of splitting the cache of the values across several machines if needed (if query load or data size grows).